# Android List<T> equivalent

Tags: android, list, generics, collections

What is the Android equivalent to the C# `List<T>`?

I have seen that java has `List<T>` in java.util but I can only seem to find the interface definition in Android 2.3.3?

Fundamentally I am looking for a generic collection that supports iteration, sort and index based access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ArrayList. [Android ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: It's not Android ArrayList, it's Java ArrayList ;)

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with it, you can choose other List implementations, ArrayList may slow down your application, when list's size is often changed.

Comment: Also if using between different threads, it's better to use Vector which is synchronized.